# Can Pycharm highlight errors after run?

Tags: python, pycharm

When I use sublime text, if my Python code has some errors after run, the editor will show the error located line.

Does Pycharm have similar capability?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. No, depending on what tool you are running it may generate a link to the code, the Python interpreter will also say the line of the error. Highlighting errors in the editor is only done by the linter and not for run-time errors.